# shower leak from back of wall

Tags: walls, shower

There is water coming from the back side of my shower head wall and spill out from there in stead of the shower head can you tell me why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

Because the showerhead isn't installed properly (or it is damaged/cracked).

First try tightening it.  They just screw on.  Make sure the threaded piece of the showerhead isn't cracked - some cheap plastic ones break quite easily, and if that is the problem you need to replace the showerhead.

Take it off and make sure there is a rubber washer inside and that it is still in good shape - if not, get a new washer for it.

If that doesn't work, get some white plumbing tape that goes around the threads to ensure a tight seal.